# Java Servlets - Front Controller Questions (Listeners & Context)

Tags: java, servlets, listener, front-controller

For the current project I'm working on, I've decided to use the front controller pattern. I've always been under the impression that a front controller should (ultimately) be responsible for everything that happens in a web app. Would listeners violate this pattern?

```
public class MyDatabase implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ...
        String driver = context.getInitParameter("driver");
    }
}
```

This, of course, seems a lot simpler than:

```
public class FrontController extends HttpServlet {
    public void service (....) {
        MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(context.getInitParameter("driver"));
    }
}
```

This is a very simplified example; there would be more parameters in practice. So, which snippet would be considered more faithful to the front controller pattern – passing the config from `FrontController` down, or supplying the config directly to the classes?

As I am new to Java, I am trying to learn servlets without using a framework (for the time being).

Comment: Don't think it is related to the question, but in the first case you are initializing the datasource,connection etc only once , i.e. when the context is initialized . In second case , this action will be repeated for each request provided all the requests are routed through the FrontController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main intent for [Front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) is to provide a centralized entry point for handling requests and consequently

> to control navigation across a set of related pages (for instance,
>   multiple pages might be used in an online purchase) from a front
>   controller than it is to make the individual pages responsible for
>   navigation

Separating responsibility of initialization of resources from Front controller pattern is good, and you choose a right place for this since `ServletContextListener` is responsible for receiving notification events about ServletContext lifecycle. Code inside `ServletContextListener` class will run before the web application starts.